# clojure: copy the contents of a directory into another directory

Tags: java, file, clojure, directory

Sounds like a simple task, and maybe it is. however I just came to this approach - is there a better way?

```clj
(require '[clojure.string :as string])

(defn mk-path [& args]
  (string/join "/" args))

(defn move-contents-to-dir [dir1 dir2]
  "Move all the contents of dir1 into dir2, which will be created if not existing."
  (doseq [file (file-seq (io/file dir1))]
    (let [base-removed (string/replace (str file)
                                       (re-pattern (str "^" (str dir1)))
                                       "")
          new-path (mk-path dir2 base-removed)]
      (io/make-parents new-path)
      (when (not (.isDirectory file))
        (io/copy file (io/file new-path))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy library called fs which implements some helpers you could use: 
http://raynes.github.io/fs/me.raynes.fs.html#var-copy-dir

Answer (score 0):

should be quite simple and speedy if you are using java 7 or above

```
(ns hello-world.core
  (:import [java.nio.file Files Paths SimpleFileVisitor StandardCopyOption FileVisitResult LinkOption CopyOption]
           [java.nio.file.attribute FileAttribute]))

(defn path [str-path]
  (Paths/get str-path (into-array String [])))

(defn copy-dir-visitor [from to]
  (proxy [SimpleFileVisitor] []
    (preVisitDirectory [dir attrs]
      (let [target (.resolve to (.relativize from dir))]
        (if-not (Files/exists target (into-array LinkOption []))
          (Files/createDirectory target (into-array FileAttribute [])))
        FileVisitResult/CONTINUE))
    (visitFile [file attrs]
      (let [target (.resolve to (.relativize from file))]
        (Files/copy file target (into-array CopyOption [StandardCopyOption/REPLACE_EXISTING])))
      FileVisitResult/CONTINUE)))

(defn copy-dir! [from to]
  (let [visitor (copy-dir-visitor from to)]
    (Files/walkFileTree from visitor)))
```